# Adding GeoCoder to Template for Story Map

Tags: geocoding, story-map

I need an step-by-step Introduction to build in an GeoCoder by Esri. I have downloaded the Story Map - Text and Legend - Template and now I am trying to build in a simple geocoder Services. But Anything works. The readme.html have an false Introduction for that. So I Need a simple step-by-step introduction.